# WebMockServer doesn't response Android Espresso

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, android-espresso, okhttp

I have configured my project well, when I debug my request I see
http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/test so CustomTestRunner and DI works.

I have setUp as:

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    hiltRule.inject()
    mockWebServer = MockWebServer()
    mockWebServer.enqueue(MockResponse().setResponseCode(200).setBody(getJson(„my_json.json")))
    mockWebServer.start(8080)
}
```

Instantly after opening my activity, App call the service api/test and it works only for true api, if I mock using webmockserver, I don't get my fake response. My method getJson returns normal Json so it works.
I have also certificate for http for android above 9, without it I got error.
Any idea ? What I should do more ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you telling your app code to use the mock server url to make requests?
Like the example in [the MockServer documentation](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver):

```
  // Ask the server for its URL. You'll need this to make HTTP requests.
  HttpUrl baseUrl = server.url("/v1/chat/");

  // Exercise your application code, which should make those HTTP requests.
  // Responses are returned in the same order that they are enqueued.
  Chat chat = new Chat(baseUrl);
```